# MAGMA-question concerning the multiplicity of indecomposable $kG$-modules in a decomposable $kG$-module

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime.

Moreover, let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, such that $p$ divides $|G|$. Furthermore suppose that $k$ is a splitting field for $G$.

Suppose that there is already stored a finite list $L=[N_1,... ,N_s]$ of indecomposable $kG$-modules, such that they are all non-isomorphic to each other.

Let $M$ be a new decomposable $kG$-module.

I know a priori that $M$ decomposes as a direct sum of indecomposable $kG$-modules $M\cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n} {M_i}$ such that

- $M_n$ is a new $kG$-module I know nothing about (except that it is indecomposable)
- all other $M_i$ are isomorphic to a module $N_j$ (for some $j$) occurring in the list $L$ from above.

Example:

$M\cong M_1\oplus M_2 \oplus M_3 \oplus M_4$ and $M_1\cong N_5$, $M_2\cong N_5$, $M_3\cong N_7$.

$M_4$ is the new module I know nothing about.

Also, I had to test with the MAGMA command "IsIsomorphic" which modules of the list $L$ my direct summands $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ of $M$ are isomorphic to.

**Question:**

> Is there an easier way to chop the modules $N_j$ off the module $M$ (with noting the multiplicities) than to decompose $M$ into all its indec. dir. summands
>   and to test  with the MAGMA command "IsIsomorphic" for every $M_i$ and $N_j$?

I'm asking this, because it costs a lot of time and memory, if $M$ is very big.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Make America Great for Math Again?

Comment: No. MAGMA is an abbreviation for Matrix Algebra for GPU and Multicore Architectures.

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler Actually, that's a different MAGMA. The Magma CAS that you are using here is not an acronym, it is named for a type of algebraic structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)

Comment: Oh...ups...ok...sorry...my fault...thanks for the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea that I've used, in an *ad hoc* way, in similar situations. I think it helped, although I can't claim to have rigorously tested how much more efficient it is.

Suppose an indecomposable module $N$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of a module $M$. Then if you choose random homomorphisms $\alpha:N\to M$ and $\beta:M\to N$, there is a reasonable probability (at least $(|k|-1)^2/|k|^2$) that $\beta\alpha$ is an isomorphism, in which case $M\cong N\oplus\ker(\beta)$.

So you could try to make $M$ smaller by randomly splitting off summands that are isomorphic to the indecomposables $N_1,\dots,N_s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the idea very much. It would be interesting to know when the "new module I know nothing about" is reached, such that I don't continue testing with modules of the list $L$ forever, although it can never be an isomorphism...Do you happen to have a trick for this as well ? :-)

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler Sorry, no, that's my only trick. In my situation I didn't know that there would only be only one new indecomposable summand, and I just used the idea I described repeatedly until I had several attempts in a row that didn't find a known summand, and then used "IndecomposableSummands".

Comment: Ok, no problem, thank you very much. Another / An additional idea would be to use "SummandIsomorphism$(M,N_j)$" for all $j$...but I should probably compare the run times before writing this...

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler I didn't know about that command. I wouldn't be at all surprised if it's much more efficient than the method I suggested!

Comment: Neither did I...I found it by coincidence very recently....I still have to check the times...